# Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'methodName': Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-batch, scheduled-tasks

plz I don't know wath is the exact problem in the code if I add Scheduled annotatiçon in my code suddenly this error appears
if you have any soulustion please.
plz I don't know wath is the exact problem in the code if I add Scheduled annotatiçon in my code suddenly this error appears
if you have any soulustion please.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
12-09-2019 18:11:54.908 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'missionResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'missionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'missionImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\El Oussa\Desktop\vgas-api\vgas-manager\target\classes\ma\valueit\vgas\manager\business\impl\MissionImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'editMission': Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
```

```
    I have added @EnableScheduling in SpringBootApplication
--------------------------------------------------------

    @SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("com.qaiboub.vs")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
    @Service
    public class MissionImpl extends CrudManagerImpl<MissionDto, Integer, MissionEntity, MissionService, MissionConverter> implements MissionManager {

    @Autowired
    private MissionService missionService;

    @Autowired
    private MissionConverter missionConverter;
    enter code here
    @Override
    public MissionService getService() {
        return missionService;
    }

    @Override
    public MissionConverter getConverter() {
        return missionConverter;
    }


    @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 18 * * *")
    public void editMission(Integer id, MissionDto missionDto) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
            throw new MissingIdException();
        }

        if (missionDto == null) {
            throw new InvalidPayloadException();
        }

        if (!id.equals(missionDto.getId())) {
            throw new BusinessException(CommonErrorCode.TRYING_TO_EDIT_ANOTHER_ENTITY);
        }

        missionEntity = missionConverter.convertFrom(missionDto);

        missionEntity = missionService.save(missionEntity);
    }

}
```

Comment: `public void editMission(Integer id, MissionDto missionDto)` is not possible you cannot have arguments in a scheduled method. It has to be `public void editMission()`

Comment: yeah yes I've already worked now,  thank u very much bro

Answer (score 3):

remove the function arg. Scheduler don't take arg in their functions

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all the arguments from the function, the scheduler does not accept any argument

```
public void syncData(@RequestParam(name = "created_at_from") String createdAtFrom,
                                                            @RequestParam(name = "created_at_to") String createdAtTo) {}
```

Correct format is

```
public void syncData() throws Exception {}
```

Use this link for additional details:
https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring